# Переопределение функции

Tags: c++, qt, переопределение

Пишу шахматы на С++ и использую Qt. Для каждый фигуры сделал свой класс и унаследовал это все от своего класса figure. Переменные класса figure не создаю, создаю переменные наследованных классов (pawn, king и прочее) и добавляю их в вектор, например:

```
vector<figure> white = {Pawn1, Pawn2, King}.
```

Хочу реализовать функцию move, которая будет отвечать за перемещение фигур, соответственно у каждого класса - король, слон, пешка, ферзь и т.д. - разная функция.
В файле figure.h:

```
virtual bool move();
```

В файле pawn.h:

```
bool move() override;
```

Собственно, проблема в чем:
Когда в исполняемом файле пишу

`white[1].move()`

то, как вы уже поняли, срабатывает функция базового класса, в чем проблема?

Comment: `vector<figure>` - вектор, хранящий объекты класса `figure`, храните в нем `unique_ptr<figure>`

Comment: Кажется, я не смогу инициализировать как unique_ptr<figure> = {Pawn1, Pawn2, King}

Comment: Так нельзя. В целом, Ваша проблема называется срезка (slicing)

Comment: На ином форуме посмотрел, что чтобы добавить в вектор объекты разных классов( унаследованных от одного общего, нужно:

vector<shared_ptr<figure>> vec;

vec.push_back<shared_ptr<figure>(new pawn());

Верное направление?

Comment: Таким образом можно реализовать Вашу идею. Но раз у Вас Qt, Может использовать классы из него?

Comment: Хотелось бы использовать свои классы, для каждой фигуры свой класс, если вы об этом.  Тогда я могу передалть вопрос в "проблема с добавлением объектов разных классов в вектор"?

Comment: Можно использовать `reference_wrapper<>`, только тогда придется вместо `white[1].move()` писать `white[1].get().move()`...

Comment: Нужно хранить указатель на объект: std::vector<figure*>;

Comment: А подскажите, как правильно очистить память, когда после сруба фигуры я удаляю из вектора ее путем white.erase(white.begin() + number)

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на свой вопрос. Как подсказал в комментариях пользователь [@e.n.shirokov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1335412/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/1335685#comment2363230_1335412) - переопределение функций было написано верно, для решения моей задачи было нужно заполнить вектор фигур не так:

```
vector<figure> white = {Pawn1, Pawn2, King}.
```

А вот так:

```
vector<figure*> white;
white.push_back(new pawn);
white.push_back(new pawn);
white.push_back(new king);
```